# Why does my panel become grainy and distorted after I unsuspend?

Tags: display, panel, suspend

I frequently suspend my computer and then bring it back, usually about twice a day.

Lately, when I bring it back, the panel at the top of the screen becomes distorted. Here is a picture.

[image: Distorted panel]

Logging out will fix the problem, although sometimes it goes away randomly. My launcher was also getting distorted, but it would fix itself as soon as I clicked something.

The functionality is fine, it appears to just be cosmetic. Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Comment: I experienced the same problem. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on an Hp Desktop, with an Nvidia (Geforce GT 430). I noticed it only happened when I changed the panel opacity. The Unity launcher is still fuzzy but clicking on it fix it. Upgraded to 12.04 Alpha2, have the same problem... hopefully, it gets fixed in the final release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be happening less now. Perhaps there was an update to fix the issue.

In any case, the only way I was able to fix it without logging off was to toggle the transparency settings for the panel in CCSM.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by toggling the transparency in MyUnity. Take it down to zero to get and then scroll back up to your usual transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar - you can fix it by toggling the "Unity Plugin" in the CompizConfig Settings Manager (aka ccsm).

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm your display driver is installed. (System Info app->Graphics)
Unity may not appear correctly without the display driver. However, many users are disappointed of Unity desktop. It's still buggy and slow. If you feel everything is slow, downgrade to Ubuntu 10 which is the most usable version. I believe things will work fine in Ubuntu 12 which will be released in April. You can tryout Luninux 11.10, which uses Gnome 3 instead of Unity. Luninux is MacOS like and developped from Ubuntu, but works better (See below). Download -->  http://luninuxos.com/?page_id=18

[image: Luninux (image from Softpedia)]

Comment: You're suggesting I downgrade or change distros because of a cosmetic bug?